# How to Create a Trigger On [table] Delete in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, delete-row

I am taking a database class and I am completely lost on this one. I hope you can help me out. Here is the SQL trigger I have created based on our text book. It says the examples are all SQL server 2012 based, but when I test the trigger it cannot recognize some of the syntaxes. Is there a way to do this differently? The `SHIPMENT_ITEM` is child of `SHIPMENT`, and its a `M-M relationship`. Thanks :)

```
CREATE TRIGGER SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck
ON [dbo].[DeleteShipmentItemView]
FOR DELETE

DECLARE
rowCount     Int;

BEGIN
/* to determine if shipment item is last one in shipment */
SELECT  Count (*) into rowCount
FROM    [dbo].[SHIPMENT_ITEM]
WHERE   [dbo].[SHIPMENT_ITEM].[ShipmentID] = old:[ShipmentID];

/*delte shipment item row regardless of wheter shipment is deleted */
DELETE  [dbo].[SHIPMENT_ITEM]
WHERE   [dbo].[SHIPMENT_ITEM].[ShipmentID] = old:[ShipmentID];

IF (rowCount = 1)
THEN
    /*last shipment item in shipment, delete shipment */
    DELETE  [dbo].[SHIPMENT]
    WHERE   [dbo].[SHIPMENT].[ShipmentID] = old:[ShipmentID];

END IF;

END;

Level 15, State 1, 
Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'rowCount'.

Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 16 Incorrect syntax near 'old:'.

Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 16 The label 'old' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.

Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 22 Incorrect syntax near 'old:'.

Procedure SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck, Line 22 The label 'old' has already been declared. Label names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

Comment: the syntax old:[ShipmentId] is not right

Comment: isn't it pl/sql instead of t-sql?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that doesn't match t-sql syntax in your trigger.

1. `DECLARE
   rowCount     Int;`
   Variables in t-sql must start with a `@` sign.
   The correct syntax would be `DECLARE @rowCount Int;`
2. `SELECT  Count (*) into rowCount`
   in t-sql, `Select into` will create a new table. you probably want `SELECT @rowCount = Count (*)` instead.
3. `[dbo].[SHIPMENT_ITEM].[ShipmentID] = old:[ShipmentID];`
   Actually, I'm not sure what you want to accomplish in this line, but it's not t-sql. I think you want to get the number of rows that was deleted. If that is the case, it's `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted`.

The way I understand your trigger, your goal is to delete a record in `SHIPMENT` table if there are no corresponding records in the `SHIPMENT_ITEM` table for it.

I would probably do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER SHIPMENT_ITEM_SHIPMENT_DeleteCheck
ON dbo.SHIPMENT_ITEM
FOR DELETE

AS 
    DELETE  
    FROM dbo.SHIPMENT s
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM deleted d 
        WHERE d.ShipmentID = s.ShipmentID
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.SHIPMENT_ITEM si
        WHERE si.ShipmentID = s.ShipmentID
    )
GO
```

**Notes:**

- This trigger contains a where clause with both `exists` and `not exists` sub queries. This ensures that you delete only the shipment's records that corresponded to the shipment_item that you have just deleted, and only if there are no other shipment_item records with the same shipmnet id.
- The trigger in the question is for a view, this is for the table itself. note that not all views in sql server are updatable, so you might need to create the trigger on the view and not directly on the shipment_item table. Also note that you can't use after triggers on a view in sql server

For more information, check the [Create trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)